# How to turn off SSL for Postgres for remote connections?

Tags: postgresql, ssl

After changing the `pg_hba.conf` file and setting it to `0.0.0.0/0` and editing the `postgresql.conf` file to `listen_addresses='*'`, Postgres is still not accepting connections from a remote system.

I think turning `ssl` off will do the work?

Comment: What exactly is the error message you get?

Comment: You are barking up the wrong tree. That error message means that "something went wrong with authentication". Read the PostgreSQL server log file to find out more. If you need help, [edit] the question and add exactly how you are trying to connect, the error message and the relevant lines from the log.

Comment: Did you restart Postgres?